# Are Questions About Making and Hanging garden gates in scope?

Tags: discussion, scope

I would like to post questions about building and hanging a garden gate.  I think this site is the best fit but I cannot see any similar questions.  The [Home Improvement](http://diy.stackexchange.com) site is the alternative but a garden gate seems too small scale and garden-related to the other questions on there.

Answer (score 3):

The [page in the help center](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) that describes on- and off-topic subjects has an entry for this in the off-topic section:

> the framing, plumbing or electrical aspects of building greenhouses, decks, or other structures (try [Home improvement](https://diy.stackexchange.com/))

(Disclaimer: the "or other structures" part used to be "etc." until I changed it just a few minutes ago while making another edit.)

It would be on-topic at [Home Improvement](https://diy.stackexchange.com/)<sup>1</sup>. Tags for [gates](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gates) and [gate-posts](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gate-post) already exist for you to use.

---

<sup>1. Source: I'm a moderator there as well. If anyone gives you guff, let me know and I'll smite them!</sup>

Comment: Yup. this site has more to do with plant care, or landscape ideas.